# Eclipse acting up

Tags: android, eclipse

I tried compiling a project that Iv ben working on for the last couple weeks, and Eclipse would not recognize my Android Device for debugging.

Then I updated Eclipse, and tried running it in the emulator and now it wont compile even. Im getting 2 errors the first

```
ERROR: Unknown option '--no-crunch'
Android Asset Packaging Tool
```

and

```
Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/Robert/Documents/workspace/BluetoothTest/bin/resources.ap_ does not exist BluetoothTest       Unknown Android Packaging Problem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem should be sorted out in r15, Please download it. :

> In Eclipse go to Help->Check for Updates

Comment: Thanks, i got it sorted out. After trying to figure it out for 2 hours.